# Setting an image as a global variable (in Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables

I am trying to set an image as a global variable. To explain it a little bit more: I have two view controllers. Viewcontroller1 is a menu and view controller 2 is a view controller with an image view.

What I would like to accomplish is to download an image in the first view controller, setting that image as a global variable and using that image in view controller2.

So far, I have this:

```
import UIKit

var globalImage = [String: UIImage]()


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // this function hides the statusbar
    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // variables for accessing web images
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.fteunen.com/app/overLay.png")
        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
            response, data, error in

            if error != nil {

                println("Something happened i guess, not good!!")
            } else {
                //let image = UIImage(data: data)
                globalImage = UIImage(data: data)
            }

        })



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

But unfortunately, this failed and at the line `globalImage = UIImage(data: data)` it gives an error saying *missing argument for parameter 'inBundle' in Call *

So, is there just a syntax error somewhere? Or is there another way of doing this? Is my idea even going to work?

Thanks in advance for your ideas and solutions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UIImage**
You are declaring `globalImage` as a `Dictionary`

```
var globalImage = [String: UIImage]()
```

and the assigning an `UIImage` to it

```
globalImage = UIImage(data: data)
```

Instead try to declare `globalImage` as a `UIImage?`

```
var globalImage:UIImage? = nil
```

The optional is used to be able to set it to nil, you can later initialize it. If there is a default image you can set it here.

When you want to declare the image you can user

```
globalImage = UIImage(data: data)
```

To use the image in your second view controller you should check if it is not nil

```
if let image = globalImage{
  //Image has been set
}else{
  //Image has NOT been set
}
```

**Dictionary**
If instead you want to use your `Dictionary` you will need to set a key for your UIImage

```
var globalImage = [String: UIImage]()
globalImage[“Second View Controller“] = UIImage(data:data)
```

You can than access this image by using

```
if let image = globalImage[“Second View Controller“] {
  //Image has been set
} else {
  //Image has NOT been set
}
```

Comment: Btw, one more small question. I have the feeling that the image is being cached somehow. When I change the overLay.png online and I restart the app, I still see the old one. How come that? Or should I ask this in a different question?

Comment: If you think you can explain your problem with enough detail and have some code to show what you’ve already tried it is best to open another question. Do you quit the app (from the multitask screen) after you try to reload the app? Since this code only runs ones one the view is created

Comment: Hi! Thank you, I found a solution. Apparently, NSURL caches a lot. So  NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
        NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().diskCapacity = 0
        NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().memoryCapacity = 0 fixes that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `globalImage` as a `Dictionary`

```
var globalImage = [String: UIImage]()
```

and the assigning an `UIImage` to it

```
globalImage = UIImage(data: data)
```

Maybe that's the problem...

If you want `globalImage` to be a UIImage, use this declaration instead:

```
var globalImage: UIImage
```

Comment: So how could I declare the globaImage in the right way? I am very new, so I have absolutely no clue :(